# Contact structure, volume form

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, contact-topology

I have the following definition for a contact structure in my lecture:

A contact structure on a manifold $W^{2n+1}$ is a hyperplane field $\xi \subset TW$ which is maximally non-integrable, meaning that the local defining forms  satisfy 
\begin{align*}
\alpha \wedge d \alpha ^n
\end{align*}
is a local volume form.

Now this confuses me, since a defining form means that locally, $\xi= ker \ \alpha$. Now let $v \in \xi$, then

$\alpha \wedge d \alpha ^n (v,v,.....,v) = 0$

since $\alpha(v)=0$, right? 
But a volume form is defined to be non-vanishing. What am I missing ?

Comment: Any time you repeat a vector as input to any $k$-form (with $k\ge 2$) you get $0$ (remember *alternating multilinear function*).

Comment: Ok I see now that I never really understood the concept of a volume form though its so basic.. Is it correct, that non vanishing just means that $\omega_p$ is not the zero map?

Comment: You need to get a better command on differential forms. A top-degree form wants to be evaluated on an (oriented) basis for the tangent space.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if I understand you right. A $n$- form $\omega$ is a section of the bundle $\wedge^nT^{*}M$, right? So $\omega_p: (T^{*}_pM)^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ .Why can volume forms only be evaluated on a basis?

Answer (score 1):

A volume-form is non-vanishing as a smooth section of the top-exterior bundle of the cotangent bundle: $\omega \in \Omega^n(M)$ is a function $\omega: M \ni p \mapsto \omega_p \in \wedge^nT^*M$. And this function should for no $p$ evaluate to zero.

Any form, now seen as a map that evaluates vectorfields, will vanish on the zero-vectorfield. So asking for a form that doesn't vanish as a map $\omega: \Gamma(TM)^n \longrightarrow C^\infty(M)$, is non-sensical.

I think this distinction is what you were missing.